# awk: filter log file based on the values in the selected column

Tags: awk, sed

Working with this kind of input data arranged in multi-column format:

```
#dlgfn #in cluster #LE #rmsd #ats #tors #h_ats #lig_eff 
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1, -2.3600, 238.8992,  80, 29, 2, -0.0303
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177,1, -2.0900, 238.8239,  80, 29, 2, -0.0268
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177,1, -1.9600, 239.3082,  80, 29, 2, -0.0251
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1, -1.9300, 238.6729,  80, 29, 2, -0.0247
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,2, -1.5500, 239.4734,  80, 29, 2, -0.0199
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1, -1.0900, 240.2418,  80, 29, 2, -0.0140
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177,1, -0.7700, 212.9619,  80, 29, 2, -0.0099
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,3, -0.7200, 218.4045,  80, 29, 2, -0.0092
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,2, -0.6800, 201.6466,  80, 29, 2, -0.0087
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_177,2, -0.6300, 240.4892,  80, 29, 2, -0.0081
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_177,1, -0.5400, 240.1765,  80, 29, 2, -0.0069
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,1, -0.5000, 215.6699,  80, 29, 2, -0.0064
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_177,1, -0.3800, 199.5818,  80, 29, 2, -0.0049
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_177,2, -0.3400, 240.5046,  80, 29, 2, -0.0044
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,1, -0.3300, 218.2226,  80, 29, 2, -0.0042
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1, -0.2700, 231.5438,  80, 29, 2, -0.0035
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_177,1, -0.0600, 200.8627,  80, 29, 2, -0.0008
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_04_lig_cne_177,2, -0.0300, 220.3135,  80, 29, 2, -0.0004
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,1, -0.0000, 221.4531,  80, 29, 2, -0.0000
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177,1,  0.0300, 231.2099,  80, 29, 2,  0.0004
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1,  0.0400, 240.5225,  80, 29, 2,  0.0005
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1,  0.0500, 232.5498,  80, 29, 2,  0.0006
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177,1,  0.0600, 229.8094,  80, 29, 2,  0.0008
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_177,2,  0.2300, 218.2757,  80, 29, 2,  0.0029
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,3,  0.2700, 220.3585,  80, 29, 2,  0.0035
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177,1,  0.3700, 219.5366,  80, 29, 2,  0.0047
```

I am using the following AWK expression to scan the log and print line number + the 2nd,3rd and 5th colums, while skiping the first (header) line:

```
   gawk -F'^[^,]*,|, ' 'NR> 1{ print ++lineNumber, $2, $3, $5 }' OFS=', ' "${tmp}"/${dir_name}_cl_${c}.txt >> "${tmp}"/${dir_name}_RG_${c_mod}_proc.csv
```

Obtaining such output:

```
ID, POP, dG, LIG
1, 1, -2.3600,  80
2, 1, -2.0900,  80
3, 1, -1.9600,  80
4, 1, -1.9300,  80
5, 2, -1.5500,  80
6, 1, -1.0900,  80
7, 1, -0.7700,  80
8, 3, -0.7200,  80
9, 2, -0.6800,  80
10, 2, -0.6300,  80
11, 1, -0.5400,  80
12, 1, -0.5000,  80
13, 1, -0.3800,  80
14, 2, -0.3400,  80
15, 1, -0.3300,  80
16, 1, -0.2700,  80
17, 1, -0.0600,  80
18, 2, -0.0300,  80
19, 1, -0.0000,  80
20, 1,  0.0300,  80
21, 1,  0.0400,  80
22, 1,  0.0500,  80
23, 1,  0.0600,  80
```

How can I modify this gawk expression to set up the filter to the 3rd column skeeping all lines from the initial log contained positive values ? Notably because the linnes are already arranged based on the value in the 3th colum, so basically each time I need to ommit N last lines (with the positive values in the third column). Alternatively can I use some sed expression (with -i) to edit the existing file, removing those linnes ?

Answer (score 0):

*How can I modify this gawk expression to set up the filter to the 3rd column skeeping all lines from the initial log contained positive values ?*

You might use `&&` for AND and `||` for OR in `awk` condition, please try following:

```
(NR>1 && $3<0.0){ print ++lineNumber, $2, $3, $5 }
```

Comment: gawk: ligne de commande:1: (NR>1 && &3>=0.0){ print ++lineNumber, $2, $3, $7 }
gawk: ligne de commande:1:                                                   ^ syntax error

Comment: @HotJAMS you typed &3 instead of $3... Double check your code

Comment: I did typo error in my answer, which I edited, please try now

Comment: Anyway, positive values are not to be printed. Moreover, this won't print the correct line numbers, as you are _not_ increasing the line number if you are not printing...

Comment: @DaemonPainter HotJAMS stated that lines to be skipped are always last ones

Comment: I've fixed it, yep it works now! So basically, since we remove always the LAST LINES (with positive values) it should not perturb the line order of the remaining lines (with negatives values), shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Daweo my bad, didn't saw that input was ordered.  Why not using [exit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) as soon as the $3 is positive? This should save some computational time

Comment: @DaemonPainter using exit would allow economize number of comparisons, but I elected not to do so as I felt it would be *premature optimization*, as it would require another action and HotJAMS question do not imply need for blazing speed

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=", " '
FNR==1{
  print "ID, POP, dG, LIG"
  next
}
$3<0{
  print ++line,2,$3,$5
}
$3>=0{ exit }'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=", " '  ##Starting awk program from here, setting FS as comma with spaces and OFS as comma space.
FNR==1{                              ##checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  print "ID, POP, dG, LIG"           ##Printing header here.
  next                               ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
$3<0{
  print ++line,2,$3,$5              ##Printing FNR-1, 2nd 3rd and 5th fields here.
}'  Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output for shown samples will be as follows:

```
ID, POP, dG, LIG
1, 2, -2.3600, 80
2, 2, -2.0900, 80
3, 2, -1.9600, 80
4, 2, -1.9300, 80
5, 2, -1.5500, 80
```

Comment: it does exactly the same like my GAWK version so printing ALL LINES, while I need to ommit all linnes containing a positive value in the third column (dG)

Comment: @HotJAMS, sure edited solution now, could you please check now once and let me know if this helps, thank you.

Comment: YES it works now thank you very much! One question, what is the difference between GAWK and AWK ? :-)

Comment: This will not print the correct line number, since you are not updating the line number if not printing...

Comment: @DaemonPainter, OP has confirmed it its working not sure why you saying its not working. I have kept `++line` in code to print line number what OP did, it should work fine for it, please do let me know where is the problem in it?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my bad, didn't saw that input was ordered.  Why not using [exit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) as soon as the $3 is positive? This should save some computational time

Comment: @DaemonPainter, I believe this should be ok too because I don't know if OP' samples could have further more negative values. So I haven't used it, you could remove downvote if looks ok now.

Comment: if further negative, unsorted values are there, then the line number is going to be wrong...

Comment: @DaemonPainter, OP has confirmed it's working fine, moreover answers are given as per shown samples,  if OP comes back with something I will edit on it, thanks.

Comment: hey, yes i confirm that in my input data the lines have already been sorted based on the third column so after 0 there are no more negative values. What I was looking for is to remove just N last linnes (that are always with positive values)

Comment: @HotJAMS, sure thanks for confirming I have added an exit so when first positive value comes code exists and save some cycles/time.